# How do I pass state variables from one screen to another in a React Native Project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, expo

My state variables are defined as follows:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
```

Both of these values are being updated via user input as follows:

```
 <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              returnKeyType="next"
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                passWord.current.focus();
              }}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              placeholder="Email Address"
              placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
              value={email}
              onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
            />
          </View>
```

I want to have access to the email and password variables on a different screen but cannot seem to figure out which hook works best in this scenario. How would I go about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you're using `navigation.navigate` but if you are you can use it as shown on the docs [seen here.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop#navigate)

Basically, after you pass the component you're trying to reach, you would pass an object containing the data you want. On the other end, you would gather that back up using `route.params` and the key/name you gave it when calling `navigate`.

My own example can be seen below:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={() => {
        navigation.navigate('TicketPurchase', {tickId: 'rollingstones'});
    }}>
    <Text style={styles.ticketbutton}>BUY TICKETS</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It was pulled in the other component as seen here: `const {tickId} = route.params;`

Comment: This approach worked for me! thankyou